# Como alocar espaço em memoria?

Tags: c, alocação

Faça um programa para alocar espaço em memória para 10 inteiros e peça ao usuário para digitar 10 valores.
Posteriormente, imprima os seus respectivos endereço de memórias e o seu conteúdo.

O que tenho que mudar no meu programa pra ele dar certo ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, *p;

    p = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));

    if (!p);
    {

        printf("Nao foi possivel alocar o vetor !");
        exit(0);

    }


    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        printf("Digite um valor: ");
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);


    }


    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        printf("Endereço de memoria: %d\nConteudo: %d\n", &p[i], p[i]);

    }


    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema que faz com que o seu programa nem mostre nada na consola é um `;` perdido, e mais no local errado:

```
if (!p);
//     ^--este
{
    printf("Nao foi possivel alocar o vetor !");
    exit(0);
```

Isso é um erro muito comum para iniciantes e acontece que o compilador normalmente não diz grande coisa, mas interpreta o código de forma diferente. No caso o `;` faz com que o `if` termine ali, e por isso o bloco de código seguinte dentro de `{}` executa sempre e como tem um `exit(0);` o programa termina sempre ali.

Depois para imprimir endereços de memória deve utilizar o formatador `%p` em vez de `%d`:

```
printf("Endereço de memoria: %d\nConteudo: %d\n", &p[i], p[i]);
//                            ^--deve ser %p
```

[Veja o código no Ideone a funcionar com esses dois erros corrigidos](https://ideone.com/Y3Mwt8)